# .htaccess rewriting query string to path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to rewrite :

http://www.test.com/api/v2/vrss.php?ET=XYZ to http://www.test.com/api/v2/vrss/XYZ

I would like that both url versions can still be used, and attempted the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/v2/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/?vrss/(.*?)/?$ /vrss.php?ET=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /vrss\.php\?ET=([^\&\ ]+) 
RewriteRule ^/?vrss\.php$ /vrss/%1? [L,R=301]
```

When var_dumping $_REQUEST, I see my values when calling the url with the query string, but am not in the rewritten path.

Can anyone let me know where I messed up?

Thanks,
S.

Comment: You can test htaccess stuff at https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Try and disable MultiViews, you likely have a problem with `vrss` getting mapped onto `vrss.php` automatically because of it.